# Can I use an SVG title tag as an input label?

Tags: svg, accessibility, pagespeed

PageSpeed Insights is complaining with "Form elements do not have associated labels" on our site.

The relevant code I'm using is:

```html
<input id="input-1" type="checkbox">
<label for="input-1">
  <svg>
    <title>This is the label text</title>
    <!-- rest of svg -->
  </svg>
</label>
```

Should this be sufficiently accessible? (I understand that using SVG icons without text is not optimal accessibility for sighted users, but that is not what PageSpeed is complaining about here.)

Comment: And this complaint is related to that very block of code?

Comment: @Andy, yes it is. (I also didn't make the code interactive, as there is very little to see )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Computation steps in the Accessible Name and Description Computation standard](https://w3c.github.io/accname/#comp_host_language_label) specifically mention the `<title>` element as a valid means to provide text for a label.

> E. Host Language Label: Otherwise, if the current node's native markup provides an attribute (e.g. alt) or element (e.g. HTML label or **SVG `title`**) that defines a text alternative, return that alternative in the form of a flat string as defined by the host language, unless the element is marked as presentational (role="presentation" or role="none").

(I emphasised the important part)

So when it comes to conformance, you’re good.

But, what is important for accessibility is also the practical part. How many users have difficulties due to insufficient support in browsers or in assistive technology? You should definitely test this.

[According to a11y support](https://a11ysupport.io/tech/svg/title_element), the SVG `<title>` element had no support in VoiceOver on iOS, and only partial support on macOS. I can confirm that it’s [still an issue in Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1324569).

I would recommend using either `aria-label` or a visually hidden element to provide alternative texts for SVG icons.

```css
/* https://www.scottohara.me/blog/2017/04/14/inclusively-hidden.html */
.visually-hidden:not(:focus):not(:active) {
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0); 
  clip-path: inset(50%);
  height: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap; 
  width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<input id="input-1" type="checkbox">
<label for="input-1">
  <svg aria-label="This is the label text" data-altlabel="svg-title" width="50" height="50">
    <title id="svg-title">This is the label text</title>
    <!-- rest of svg -->
    <rect width="50" height="50" fill="#cc0000"></rect>
  </svg>
</label>

<input id="input-2" type="checkbox">
<label for="input-2">
  <span class="visually-hidden">This is the label text</span>
  <svg aria-hidden="true" width="50" height="50">
    <!-- rest of svg -->
    <rect width="50" height="50" fill="#cc0000"></rect>
  </svg>
</label>
```

Comment: You're absolutely right, esp. VoiceOver was a surprise to me. Interestingly, not even your input-1 label got announced on my test-iPhone 8. Adding role=img did get it announced, but now twice (once for the input, and once with the addition of image). The visually-hidden text works best. Testing is so important...

Answer (score 2):

After some trying, this solution actually seems best. It has the cleanest code, is accepted by PageSpeed, and works on my old iPhone 8.

```html
<input id="input-1" type="checkbox" aria-label="This is the label text">
<label for="input-1">
  <svg role="none">
    <!-- rest of svg -->
  </svg>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @andy but here's a slight variation on his code that might be a bit simpler. His first example shows adding an ID to the <title> but then you also need to reference that ID in the `aria-labelledby` of the <input>.

```
<input id="input-1" type="checkbox" aria-labelledby="titleID">
<label for="input-1">
  <svg>
    <title id="titleID">This is the label text</title>
    <!-- rest of svg -->
  </svg>
</label>
```

When you do this, the actual `<label for=...>` becomes superfluous because the <label> will be ignored due to `aria-labelledby` having precedence, as noted in the "[Computation steps in the Accessible Name and Description Computation standard](https://w3c.github.io/accname/#comp_computation)" that @andy posted. So you could just have the <svg> *not* contained in a <label>, which makes the code even simpler.

```
<input id="input-1" type="checkbox" aria-labelledby="titleID">
<svg>
  <title id="titleID">This is the label text</title>
  <!-- rest of svg -->
</svg>
```

Comment: This unfortunately takes away the possibility to click the SVG to check the box, which help with usability as well, the target is bigger.

Comment: @Andy, yes, of course. Good catch. My main point was using an ID on the \<title> and  referencing it from `aria-labelledby`, which was my first example.